# One of My Classes is Returning a Wrong Value

Tags: c#

I an using C#.

I have 9 classes in total.

3 classes are abstract classes, and the rest are concrete classes.

Each of those class is supposed to return Area and volume (for three-dimensional shapes).

All classes are working fine except the cube class, which is returning 0.

I changed from using the variable to using property, but still, I was getting 0.

My test class looks like this:

```
Shape[] shapes =
        {
            new Sphere ("A sphere is a sphere", 10),
            new Cube ("A cube is a cube", 10),
            new Tetrahedron ("Tetrahedron is a tetra", 10),
            new Circle ("a circle is a circle", 10),
            new Triangle ("a triangle is a triangle", 10, 10),
            new Square ("a square is a square", 10),

        };
        foreach (Shape s in shapes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( s );
        }
```

My cube class looks like this:

```
class Cube : ThreeDimensionalShape
{
    private double side; //holds side value

    public Cube ()
    {

    }
    public Cube (string desc, double s )
        :base (desc)
    {
        Side = side;
    }

    public double Side
    {
        get
        {
            return side;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Side of cube must be greater or equal to 0" );
            }
            else
            {
                side = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public override double Area
    {
        get
        {
            return 6 * ( side * side ); //return cube area
        }
    }
    public override double Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Math.Pow (Side, 3);
        }
    }

}
```

My output looks like this:

```
A sphere is a sphere
Area = 314.159265358979
Volume = 523.598775598299

A cube is a cube
Area = 0
Volume = 0

Tetrahedron is a tetra
Area = 173.205080756888
Volume = 117.851130197758

a circle is a circle
Area = 314.159265358979

a triangle is a triangle
Area = 50

a square is a square
Area = 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just affect s to Side instead of side in the cube constructor

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not using the constructor parameter `s` when setting the `Side` property so the `side` has it's default value 0.

You have parameter name called `s` in constructor:

```
public Cube (string desc, double s )
```

while you are setting the Side property in constructor with value in `side` variable which is field in your `Cube`.

Adjust your line in constructor body from:

```
Side = side;
```

to:

```
Side = s;
```

Comment: Yeah it's funny how I was going crazy about this. Thanks